# python execute a bot with credentials in text/excel file, loop until the end of the list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is what I tend to achieve

[image: What I tend to achieve]

I want to take username and password line by line from a text file and execute a bot by using every username and password.
I am just learning Selenium right now.

```py
def get_credentials() -> dict: 
    # dictionary for storing credentials 
    credentials = dict() 

    # reading the text file  
    # for credentials 
    with open('credentials.txt') as f:
        # interating over the lines 
        for line in f.readlines(): 
            try: 
                # fetching email and password 
                key, value = line.split(": ") 
            except ValueError: 
                # raises error when email and password not supplied 
                print('Add your email and password in credentials file') 
                exit(0)

            # removing trailing  
            # white space and new line 
            credentials[key] = value.rstrip(" \n") 

    # returning the dictionary containing the credentials 
    return credentials
```

and then I am using the credentials here to my main.py

```py
import auto as ed
import secrets, sys 

credentials = secrets.get_credentials()

# initialize the bot with your credentials 
bot = ed.testbot(credentials['email'], credentials['password']) 

# loging in 
bot.login()
```

Comment: It might be just my impression but your post isn't very clear in what you need help with

Comment: ahh okay, please refer the image i am just having a hard time with how to execute it with for loop